# MacPro Early 2008, how to hook up yellow power cords to the graphics card?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro

I'm tearing apart my MacPro Early 2008, cleaning it, and putting it back together.

Most of it seems to be going back together fine but one part confuses me and that's the two bundles of yellow wires that connect from the motherboard to the giant red video card;

The two little black plugs on the end are where the yellow cables connect:

[image: Large red video card with two little connectors on the right of the card]

I'd like to know in which order they connect or if it even matters at all since they have the same plug adapter head on each of them.  The yellow coated wires come from the upper front of the case (towards the dual fans up front) on the motherboard and used to connect to the video card on the side closest to the CPUs.

[image: Large red video card part number]

Answer (score 1):

The two power cables are interchangeable. Order is unimportant.

They were originally envisaged as one per card, in 2 PCI slots, but they're duplicates of one another.

From the Service Source Manual

[image]